How to correctly sign Mac app with xcodebuild
I'm trying to build my Mac app for TestFlight using xcodebuild but I keep getting errors about the provisioning profile not containing the Mac Developer Installer Certificate. The release configuration works fine when archiving in Xcode so I know the provisioning profiles have the correct App Store Distribution configurations, but the same settings don't seem to work with xcodebuild. Here's the error:
error: exportArchive Provisioning profile "Testing Tools Extenstion Distribution" doesn't include signing certificate "3rd Party Mac Developer Installer: Andrew Brown (ZME7ED67F3)".

error: exportArchive Provisioning profile "Mac Distribution (Test)" doesn't include signing certificate "3rd Party Mac Developer Installer: Andrew Brown (ZME7ED67F3)".

** EXPORT FAILED **

And here's the command I'm trying to run:
xcodebuild archive \
  -project TestingTools.xcodeproj \
  -scheme TestingToolsExtension \
  -sdk macosx \
  -configuration Release \
  -derivedDataPath DerivedData \
  -archivePath DerivedData/Archive/TestingTools

xcodebuild -exportArchive \
  -archivePath DerivedData/Archive/TestingTools.xcarchive \
  -exportOptionsPlist provisioning/App-Store.plist \
  -exportPath DerivedData/ipa

Where App-Store.plist is:
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>compileBitcode</key>
    <false/>
    <key>method</key>
    <string>app-store-connect</string>
    <key>teamID</key>
    <string>ZME7ED67F3</string>
    <key>uploadBitcode</key>
    <false/>
    <key>uploadSymbols</key>
    <true/>
    <key>signingStyle</key>
    <string>manual</string>
    <key>signingCertificate</key>
    <string>3rd Party Mac Developer Application: Andrew Brown (ZME7ED67F3)</string>
    <key>provisioningProfiles</key>
    <dict>
        <key>com.andybrown.TestingTools</key>
        <string>Mac Distribution (Test)</string>
        <key>com.andybrown.TestingTools.TestingToolsExtension</key>
        <string>Testing Tools Extenstion Distribution</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>

Note: This is a Mac app for an Xcode extension, so there are two targets: the main app and the extension.
Does anyone have any suggestions for where I'm going wrong please?
